# How to use 'gcloud deployment-manager deployments' within 'gcloud builds' do have a full CI/CD pipeline on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-build, google-deployment-manager

I am trying to setup a CI/CD pipeline on GCP. I would like following:

- new modification in Github is used as a trigger
- use `gcloud builds submit --config=cloud_build.yaml` to build a new docker image that contain the modification from git (mainly new python packages and python code) and push the image in ContainerRegistry
- use `gcloud deployment-manager deployments` create xxx -- template pipeline.jinja --properties xxx` to deploy and run my container (it is a jupyter notebook)

I have the 2 last steps setup and working (`gcloud` and `gcloud deployment-manager`).

My question is how can I do that with one script ? I would line to have the pipeline fully automated. Some of the test I would like to implement is to test that python packages are installed properly will be done on the container after the deployment.

What is the best practices on GCP ? I was thinking that I could use `gcloud deployment-manager` inside `gcloud builds` but didn't really find documentation up to know how to do that. For the deployment, I have a lot of variables to pass to setup network, machine type and other parameters and I can only do it using jinja script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best practices on GCP ? I was thinking that I could use gcloud 
>   deployment-manager inside gcloud builds but didn't really find
>   documentation up to know how to do that

Cloud Build provides and maintains pre-built images of builders that you can reference in your build steps to execute your tasks.

You can trigger the deployment manager using the `gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud` ([doc](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gcloud)) builder:

```
# Build images
[...]

# Load/Generate your Jinja templates
[...]

# Deploy
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  id: Deploy your application
  args: ['deployment-manager', 'deployments', 'create', 'your-template']
```

However, there are more *conventional* ways to deploy containerized application within a GKE cluster:

- via `gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl` to directly deploy application via well-defined Kubernetes manifests;
- via [Helm tool builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/helm) to package and deploy Kubernetes applications starting from custom templates.

---

*Disclaimer: Comments and opinions are my own and not the views of my employer.*